# Why is SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI set to "sqlite:///:memory:" when I set it to a path in my Config?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am learning Flask by following Miguel Ginsberg mega tutorial chapter 4. When I run any Flask command from the Anaconda command panel I get an error that includes "Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set." and as a result an SQLite database is created in memory.

But I have created a Config object that sets SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SECRET_KEY and SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS, and have tested the python separately, and it all works.

I have tried everything I can think of including testing snippets of code separately, at least 8 hours searching the web, and trawling though Ginsberg's posts, nothing works. One person Graham (post #29) seems to have had the same problem but Ginsberg does not give a useful answer.

Here is my app init code

```
__init__

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

Here is my config, it works when run separately.

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

For completeness here are my routes and models

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from app import app
from app.forms import LoginForm


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Miguel'}
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'username': 'John'},
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'username': 'Susan'},
            'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
        }
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, posts=posts)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
            form.username.data, form.remember_me.data))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html',  title='Sign In', form=form)
```

and

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)
```

What should happen is that when I run a command like

```
> flask db init
```

or

```
> flask db migrate -m "users table"
```

the command should complete successfully because SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI should equal the path of the app and the SQLite database should be app.db.

Instead I get error messages stating SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is not set and that therefore SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI has been set to "sqlite:///:memory:"

My app needs a persistent database! Why isn't SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI and SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS being set?

Comment: Can’t really blame Miguel for his response to #29. What do you getwhen you stick a print stmt ( with `os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')` etc) in the Config class. Are you using Anaconda Project?

Comment: Miguel is brilliant and i am learning heaps from his mega tutorial. I can make it work by not importing the Config and instead hard-coding the config variables directly into __init__ like this ```app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] =...```. I see why this works but still can't see why the Config class approach doesn't work for me. It must work for everyone else because it's in Miguel's heavily used tutorial!

Comment: It also does not work for me. I think it's because the environmental variables are not set when you run the database migrate commands, but only when you run `flask run` because this runs the  `.flaskenv` file made (for those who followed that approach). My guess was that the `basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` call fails for some reason, and hence it defaults to the memory location. But adding a print in config.py shows it is alright. I also tried the `'sqlite://' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')` which looks fine. I don't understand the issue either.

Answer (score 4):

this problem has gone away by itself, but since others may experience it I decided to describe the work-around I used to save them some frustration. I think the original problem may have been due to the sequence in which I was importing packages/modules and initiating classes/objects into my `__init__` method.

The workaround is to comment out the original config statement and directly set the config variables, including the SQLite database, in `__init__`.

```
### app.config.from_object(Config)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
     'sqlite:///' + 'C:\\...path...\\app.db'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
...
```

The workaround can probably be backed off a little by using

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

...

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
...
```